# T SQL Count question

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I'm making a report at work which looks at 5 columns which all contain v1aa, v1ab and v1ac.

What I want to do is count up all the v1aa in the 5 columns and show the results (and the same for v1ab and v1ac)

An example of how I like it to be displayed as is as follows :-

```
Amber = 3 (v1aa code)
Blue =  2 (v1ab code)
Red  = 1 (v1ac code)
```

Could anyone give me any tips how to get me started?

Comment: Could you post some example data?

Answer (score 1):

I'd need to see the data to be sure, but is sounds like a [cross tab query](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1019).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
SELECT
    SUM((CASE WHEN Column1 = 'v1aa' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        + (CASE WHEN Column2 = 'v1aa' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        + (CASE WHEN Column3 = 'v1aa' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        + (CASE WHEN Column4 = 'v1aa' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        + (CASE WHEN Column5 = 'v1aa' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))
    AS Amber,
    SUM((CASE WHEN Column1 = 'v1ab' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        + (CASE WHEN Column2 = 'v1ab' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        + (CASE WHEN Column3 = 'v1ab' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        + (CASE WHEN Column4 = 'v1ab' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        + (CASE WHEN Column5 = 'v1ab' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))
    AS Blue,
    SUM((CASE WHEN Column1 = 'v1ac' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        + (CASE WHEN Column2 = 'v1ac' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        + (CASE WHEN Column3 = 'v1ac' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        + (CASE WHEN Column4 = 'v1ac' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        + (CASE WHEN Column5 = 'v1ac' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))
    AS Red
FROM
    dbo.MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will get you started. You might need to add a WHERE clause if NULLs are a possibility or additional codes are possible in the data that you do not want to show in your report.

```
SELECT CASE i.code
    WHEN 'v1aa' THEN 'Amber'
    WHEN 'v1ab' THEN 'Blue'
    WHEN 'v1ac' THEN 'Red' END,
    COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT Col1 AS Code FROM Test
    UNION ALL SELECT Col2 FROM Test
    UNION ALL SELECT Col3 FROM Test
    UNION ALL SELECT Col4 FROM Test
    UNION ALL SELECT Col5 FROM Test
) i
GROUP BY i.Code
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want these counts for each record, then try:

```
Select
    Case When Col1 Like '%v1aa%' Then 1 Else 0 End +
    Case When Col2 Like '%v1aa%' Then 1 Else 0 End +
    Case When Col3 Like '%v1aa%' Then 1 Else 0 End +
    Case When Col4 Like '%v1aa%' Then 1 Else 0 End +
    Case When Col5 Like '%v1aa%' Then 1 Else 0 End As AmberCount,
    Case When Col1 Like '%v1ab%' Then 1 Else 0 End +
    Case When Col2 Like '%v1ab%' Then 1 Else 0 End +
    Case When Col3 Like '%v1ab%' Then 1 Else 0 End +
    Case When Col4 Like '%v1ab%' Then 1 Else 0 End +
    Case When Col5 Like '%v1ab%' Then 1 Else 0 End As BlueCount,
    Case When Col1 Like '%v1ac%' Then 1 Else 0 End +
    Case When Col2 Like '%v1ac%' Then 1 Else 0 End +
    Case When Col3 Like '%v1ac%' Then 1 Else 0 End +
    Case When Col4 Like '%v1ac%' Then 1 Else 0 End +
    Case When Col5 Like '%v1ac%' Then 1 Else 0 End As RedCount
From MyTable
```

If you want the counts for the entire table then add a Sum() aggregation function, as Timothy Khouri suggested in his answer